# Using a hierarchy from one table to another

Tags: powerbi, dax

[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6cV5.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6cV5.jpg)

[image]

Hi I am doing a graph with data from one table , I would like to use in the filter a hierarchy from another table but I don't know how to do it.
Anyway could help? I just begin in Power BI

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have a relationship established between the two tables. If you just want to use the fields within the hierarchy as a filter, you can drag and drop the fields into the filter pane and use it there. If you want to use a slicer and the entire hierarchy, you would have to use the "Hierarchy Slicer" from the marketplace. If you haven't imported visuals from the marketplace before, you can do it by clicking on the three dots (...) at the end of the "Visualizations" pane and selecting "Import from marketplace". Then search for Hierarchy slicer and import it.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380820?tab=Overview

Hope this helps.